# Unable to create "SUBMIT"button in InfoPath 2013

Tags: infopath, submit

I'm having problem in creating "SUBMIT"button in a InfoPath 2013. Received below error.

Please assist..

[image]

Comment: Please provide the complete error you got?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see the Document Library URL you are giving is wrong. It should be something like

```
https://ceosuite365.sharepoint.com/mylibrary
```

where you should replace 'mylibrary' with the name of your library as it appears in the url. Remove all that "..._layouts/15/..." stuff. In your case I think it should be

```
https://ceosuite365.sharepoint.com/checkinandcheckout
```

By the way, I would like to advise you to be careful when creating bound infopath forms for a SharePoint document library. If you want to change the form later on and if you have too many documents already created in the library you might get an irreversible error which won't allow you to publish the infopath form to SharePoint. I recommend that you create a SharePoint list and customize it with Infopath instead. Other option is also to look into Microsoft Outllok to create forms.

Hope this helps.